# Is there a right way to provide an empty operand to an equals sign?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Imagine you intend to have "x=" in your document, followed by something that cannot be rendered in math mode, nor within some sort of box within math mode. Is there a preferred way to treat the right operand of the equals sign? Perhaps one of the following?

```
$x=$ something
$x={}$ something
$x=\mathord{}$ something
$x=\mathstrut$ something
```

or any of the above without the space between the closing dollar sign and the 's'? Or just go with whatever looks good to you?

So far I've been going with

```
$x={}$something
```

But it was suggested to me that this is a hack, and that maybe

```
$x=\mathstrut$something
```

would be preferred.

Comment: You have `\text{}` to insert in math mode, but if it is impossible to insert `something` in math, then the first is the closest one. Without too much effort.

Comment: OK, so it's `$x=$ something` and definitely not `$x=$something`. I had some automated LaTeX stuff going on where the space after closing math mode was not automatically generated. It looked bad, so that's when I started putting empty right operands in there. But it turns out I just need a space character after closing math mode.

Comment: @AboAmmar But there is still a slight difference between `$x=$ something` and `$x={}$something`. Is it a sure thing that the former is better? To my understanding the latter is actually balancing space around the equals sign better.

Comment: Also, when `something` is just the word "something", and so therefore insertible within the math mode, then `$x={}$something` seems to agree with `$x=\text{something}$` whereas `$x=$ something` does not.

Comment: Please, give more information about *cannot be rendered in math mode*. In may cases it is possible to insert some textual content inside a math mode using some special tricks and then you can keep all the math structure preserved.

Comment: @Sigur It's not text. One example might be an image file inclusion. I just am trying to keep it simple with "something".

Answer (score 6):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

I have attached a picture alongside its generating code for comparison. You can click on the image for a bigger view (nice feature new to TeX.SX). Paying a close look, you observe a perfect alignment between first and fourth expressions where both come from mathmode. The second nearest is the third, then comes the second the fifth and the sixth (which are all the same). But a big difference between the second and the third exists. If I can't follow the fourth, I would follow the third!

Comment: I don't think this picture is worth a thousand words. Why not `$x={}$something`?

Comment: Wouldn't the space in the third option `$x=$ something` depend on the paragraph formatting? I mean, it's just an interword space in text mode, so it *can* be modified, no? I think that @Manuel suggestion is the best one.

Comment: `$x=\text{something}$` is the right thing to go for (or also `$x=\mbox{something}$`, in a case like this).  In “normal” circumstances, @Manuel’s suggestion `$x={}$something$` yields exactly the same result, as you can check with `\showlists`, but beware of `\mathsurround`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Apart from `\mathsurround` which is usually of no problem, the benefit of leaving `something` outside of math mode (technically outside of a box) is that it can be hyphenated, and for instance it can stretch or shrink a little bit with `microtype`.

Comment: @Manuel: That’s true too, and in fact my comment was in the direction of supporting your solution. :-)  However, often you want precisely to *prevent* hyphenation of words included in math formulas, but this may depend on the circumstances, _e.g.,_ on whether `$x$` is equal to a single word or to a whole sentence.  So, I withdraw my statement about the “right thing to go for”, I’d rather say “it depends”.  While we are at it, it may be interesting to note that character protrusion *is* applied “through” `$` and the `\mbox` construction, as long as `\mathsurround=0pt`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion I caused in OP. This is not about abutting some text, like the word "something". I was just trying to represent a generic object. The "something" might be say an image inclusion. I did say _something that cannot be rendered in math mode_. I am counting a `\text{}` as something that _can_ be rendered within math mode.

Comment: @alex.jordan: If it *is* an image inclusion, then, _e.g.,_ `$x=\includegraphics[scale=…]{imageName}$` works fine (it creates a math list with Ord, Rel, Ord atoms).  And it is “`\mathsurround`-safe”… ;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti OK, it's not an image inclusion though. It's something too complicated to get into here involving another application that uses LaTeX. But LaTeX is just a tool being used by this other application. It's too much to get into, but it's something I just cannot include inside the math mode delimiters.

Comment: @alex.jordan: Follow Manuel’s advice, then.

Comment: @Manuel (Please do not think I’m too fussy, but in the interest of exactitude): It occured to me that, in `$x={}$something`, actually the word “something” *cannot* be hyphenated, because it does not follow a glue item (see Appendix H, p. 454, first sentence of second double dangerous bend).  You can check this with `\showhyphens`.  EDIT: but of course you can apply the usual trick of adding `\nobreak\hskip 0pt \relax`.